# Iterating through all slots that are not null, 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I must work with a 2d array. The maximum length of the row slots in the array is 100. More often than not, anywhere from 5-20 of these array slots will be filled and not more, however, I must build my code to a max of 100 rows. My question is, is there a way to iterate through only the array slots that have been set, stopping before the last unset, null slots?

```
//initialize array
String[][] variables = new String[numVariables][100];

//System.out.printf("%s \n", numVariables);

for(int i=0; i < numVariables; i++){
    //reads in variable line
    String variableLine = fin.nextLine();

    //turn variable line into array
    varArray = variableLine.split(" ");

    numRules = Integer.parseInt(varArray[0].replaceAll("\\s",""));

    for(int j=0; j < numRules+1; j++){
        variables[i][j] = varArray[j+1];

        System.out.printf("%s ", variables[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

//**LATER IN MY CODE ****//
//ITERATE THROUGH 'variables' array and PRINT OUT ONLY VALUES THAT ARE SET
```

Comment: Is it really a requirement to use an array? If null values occur often and are a "problem", a better way probably would be to use some other standard structure, like a List or maybe a Map, if the position is relevant for you.

Comment: Yes, it is a requirement, as it says in the very first line of the post. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you populate the array in order from 0 to 100. If the first 51 elements are populated with the string then you could use:

```
    for(int i=0; i < numVariables; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < numRules+1; j++){
            if (variables[i][j] == null)
                break;
            System.out.printf("%s ", variables[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This a simple solution that does exactly what I need. Thank you! Will mark as solution after some testing...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even store the nulls if you don't need them? A `String[][]` is an array of arrays of String - those inner arrays need not have the same length. You could therefore create each inner array with the number of elements it needs:

```
           //initialize array
            String[][] variables = new String[numVariables][];

            //System.out.printf("%s \n", numVariables);

            for(int i=0; i < numVariables; i++){
                //reads in variable line
                String variableLine = fin.nextLine();

                //turn variable line into array
                varArray = variableLine.split(" ");

                numRules = Integer.parseInt(varArray[0].replaceAll("\\s",""));

                variables[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(varArray, 1, numRules - 1);
            }
```

and then iterate:

```
for (String[] var : variables) {
    for (String s : var) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: given the odd requirements, I'm sure his homework problem makes him instantiate it as a 100 element array.  also, shouldn't `new String[][numVariables]` be `new String[numVariables][]`?

Comment: @PeterElliott: You're right about the syntax, fixed that. As for whether he needs a fixed length: Nothing in the code he posted would make that necessary - but who knows he is trying to accomplish with that array?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an array of `List<String>` or you can also keep track of the length of all your rows.

```
int [] rowLength = new int[numVariables]

for(int i=0; i < numVariables; i++){
    /* ... */

    numRules = Integer.parseInt(varArray[0].replaceAll("\\s",""));

    // store the number of slots in variable[i]
    rowLength[i] = numRules+1;

    /* ... */
}
```

Then you iterate only from zero to the length of your row (`rowLength[i]`).

A third approach (and **the one I would prefer**) is to not specify the length of the row slots in your array :

```
String [][] variables = new String[numVariables][];
```

Then after having calculated numRules:

```
variables[i] = new String[numRules+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the situation you have described you'd probably be better off using another data structure, but seeing as you cannot you could keep a record of what values have been changed.

So you could keep an array of the length of each row and end each search there for the row.

```
    String[][] variables = new String[numVariables][100];
    int rowLength[] = new int[numVariables];

    //...
    // get and record the rowLength
    //...

    for(int x=0; x < numVariables; x ++) {
        for(int y=0; y < rowLength[x]; y ++) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could use a map or ArrayList to keep track of each of the positions that contain numbers.